# Insert Emoji to <p:textEditor> or <p:inputTextarea> on primefaces

Tags: primefaces, emoji

I'm developing a project of chat with Java EE and Primefaces.
Now, I'm wanting to add Smiley when sending message to my friend, the message is written on **p:inputTextarea** or **p:textEditor**.

for general case, I have:

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"> 
 <h:head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <link href="stylesheets/jquery.cssemoticons.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="javascripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="javascripts/jquery.cssemoticons.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function()
   {
    $('.text').emoticonize({
    //delay: 800,
    //animate: false,
    //exclude: 'pre, code, .no-emoticons'
    });
    $('#toggle-headline').toggle(
    function(){
     $('#large').unemoticonize({
      //delay: 800,
      //animate: false
     })
    }, 
    function(){
     $('#large').emoticonize({
      //delay: 800,
      //animate: false
     })
     }
    );
   })
  </script>
  <style type="text/css">
   #small { font-size: 8px; }
   #large { font-size: 72px; }
   #regular { font-size: 20px; }
   .wrapped { width: 350px; }
  </style>
 </h:head> 
 <h:body> 
  
  <h:outputText value="Hello World!!!! :)" styleClass="text"/>
 
 </h:body> 
</html>
```

As result, it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJOkp.png).
Now, I'm wanting to have a list of emoji and after selecting one, it's automatically added to my input text.

Have you please any idea about doing that? Thanks a lot.

Comment: please post some code that you have tried so far. Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hi @SouravGhosh , thanks a lot for your reply. I made changes to my question, could you please take a look, thanks.